# ImportError: No module named pygal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror, pygal

I'm using:

```
macOS Catalina 10.15.1
VSCode 1.40.2
Python 3.8.0 64-bit
```

I'm stalling pygal trough: `pip3 install --user pygal` and OK DONE.
But, when import pygal on VScode it return error like this-> `ImportError: No module named pygal`

Someone can help me? Look the 1st line of the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY9sk.jpg)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the same python environment in both commands ?

Comment: you many have two (or more) Pythons installed and you install module in one Python but VScode uses other Python to run script. Check `pip3 -V` and `python3 -V` in console to see versions.

Comment: you may have installed also `3.7` (or `3.6`) and `pip3` may install modules for `3.7`, not `3.8` - using `pip3 -V` you will see if it works with `3.8` or other version. You may have also `pip3.7` and `pip3.8` to install modules in selected version.

Comment: BTW: the same you can have `python3`, `python3.7`, `python3.8` and then you can install modules in 3.8 using `python3.8 -m pip install pygal`

Comment: Pip3 is 3.8 Version and
Python is 3.8 version to.
Can be some problem with VScode?

Comment: screen shows that it runs `python`, not `python3` . Maybe `python -V` is different version. Other posibilities: VScode has installed own version of Python and it use it, If you use virtualenv then you forgot to activate it before installing module.

Comment: I done python3.8 -m pip install pygal and look -> Requirement already satisfied: pygal in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (2.4.0)

Comment: you could check `python -V` and `python -m pip install pygal` in terminal VScode

Comment: ooowwww in my Vscode shown Python 2.7.16... How can I change to 3.8?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is working!!
1. Even changing the version of Python in VS code, when I type: "python -V" in VS code terminal, it shows version 2.7.16
2. Already installed pygal within version 3.8 and even and apparently confirm the installation, but when I run a code "import pygal", the message appears: ImportError: No module named pygal

I don't know what would be the way to get it right. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that Sublime uses the same Python interpreter that you installed Pygal in. I am not too familiar with macOS; Sublime might use the system interpreter by default, or a system-wide side-packages folder, rather than a local one. Start an interactive session by calling python3 in your console and try to import Pygal from there. If that works, your problem is likely related to Sublime using a different interpreter/env than what your installation was perfomed in.

Comment: He is not using sublime.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Check if you installed the pygal interpreter and if you don't have it installed installed it. Happens to me all the time.